# Epoch size (in terms of iterations) with data augmentation caffe

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

Suppose if one has training examples, and his batch size is 500, then it will take 2 iterations to complete 1 epoch. Now let's say I am using the caffe framework's on the fly data-augmentation, i.e; 10 crops per example.
My question is will the epoch size will still be 2 iterations as in the above examples or become 2*10 = 20?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An epoch is the the number of iterations it takes to go over the training data once. Since you augment your data, it will take you 10 times more iterations to complete one pass over the training data. Hence `1 epoch = 2*10 iterations` now.

Comment: So, by extension if my batch size is say 100, then in 1 iteration only 10 real training examples (not crops) will be covered. Am I right?

Comment: @Shai I couldn't find any evidence of that on the Caffe [source-code](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/src/caffe/data_transformer.cpp#L354). Based on your answer, if we remove the `transform_param` from a Data Layer, we should expect a faster training (far less images), correct? I did this experiment, set the crop to be only 1 pixels smaller than the original input size, and the training time and GPU memory used were marginally the same. I think on-the-fly data augmentation is meant to vary images between epochs only, virtually augmenting the number of images seen by the network.

Comment: @Berriel AFAIK, if you remove the augmentation from `transform_param` in `"Data"` layer, you simply process more "real" images per batch. However, batch size will remain the same and so is the number of iterations caffe does, so you will **not** see an actual decrease in runtime.

Comment: @Shai sure, I also expected that. What I mean is that Deven's comment seems to be wrong, isn't it? For a batch size of 100, in 1 iteration, 100 different real training examples will be used, each one with a random transformation, correct? I'm interested on this because it could be leading to a bug on the DIGITS from NVIDIA, where users set number of epochs instead of number of iterations.

Comment: @Berriel whoo... one really need to dig into the code for that, or to get an answer from a more credible source. I do not qualify at this point.

Comment: @Berriel please make your findings public. Adding a more credible answer here is an option. Thanks!